# Render table columns only once using knockout conditional statement

Tags: html, knockout.js, conditional-statements

I am having two collections parent and child. For every parent row, I am rendering child rows in a html table based on a condition which is when parent record id equals child record id. The html looks like below:

```
   <tbody data-bind="foreach: $root.subGridRows">
          <tr data-bind="foreach: $root.subGridColumns">
             <!-- ko if: $parents[1][$root.parentRecordKey] === $parent[$root.childRecordKey] -->
                   <td>
                      <span data-bind="text: header"></span>
                   </td>
             <!-- /ko -->
            </tr>
   </tbody>
```

I want to render the column containing span element only once for all the rows. I cannot eliminate the knockout condition used above because that renders the column only for those child records whose ID matches with parent record id.

Comment: Your question is really unclear without the corresponding view model code. Please edit your question and make sure the code has a [minimal repro](http://sscce.org) of your situation.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to understand your question, but it sounds like moving the `foreach` out of the `tr` and into it's own virtual `foreach` would solve your problem. For example:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: $root.subGridRows">
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="if: $parent[$root.parentRecordKey] === $data[$root.childRecordKey]">
            <span data-bind="text: header"></span>
        </td>
        <!-- foreach: $root.subGridColumns -->
            <td>Display other columns here</td>
        <!-- /ko -->
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

That might be slightly off, and the code is untested, but it should help you solve your problem.